# Reshape Pandas dataframe with repeating item counts on multiple columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, df, where I would like to reshape from wide to long, changing the column names and adding 0's for empty numerical cells.

It is taking into consideration the count under each `r_hi`, `r_hey` etc.

In desired output `r_type` has 6 rows due to: `r_hi` (2) and `r_hey` (4) equaling 6. Then we add `d_hi`, and `d_hey` onto a separate column `d_type` side by side with `r_type`.

**Data**

```
id  date    r_hi    r_hey   d_hi    d_hey   occupied    remaining
aa  q122    2       4       2       3       10          2
bb  q222    0       1       0       0       2           1
```

**Desired**

```
id  date    r_type  d_type  occupied    remaining
aa  q122    hi      hi      10          2   
aa  q122    hi      hi      10          2   
aa  q122    hey     hey     10          2   
aa  q122    hey     hey     10          2   
aa  q122    hey     hey     10          2   
aa  q122    hey     0       10          2   
bb  q222    hey     0       2           1
```

**Doing**

Utilize the melt function:

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['id', 'date'], value_vars=['occupied', 'remaining'])
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: Why are there 7 rows instead of 4? Are the number of hi and hey the numerical values in the field?

Comment: it is taking into consideration the count under each 'r_hi', r_hey' etc-   r_type already has 6 rows due to: r_hi (2) and r_hey (4) equaling 6. Then we add d_hi, and d_hey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can approach by the following steps:

```
df2 = df.set_index(['id', 'date', 'occupied', 'remaining'])

# Split column label to multi-level index for stacking
df2.columns = df2.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)

# Stack level 1 column index 'hi', 'hey' into row index
df3 = df2.stack()

# duplicate 'hi', 'hey' into number of rows 
# according to values in `r_hi`, `r_hey`, `d_hi`, `d_hey`  
df4_d = df3.loc[df3.index.repeat(df3['d'])]
df4_r = df3.loc[df3.index.repeat(df3['r'])]

# transform layouts
df4_da = df4_d.reset_index(level=4)[['level_4']].rename({'level_4': 'd_type'}, axis=1)
df4_ra = df4_r.reset_index(level=4)[['level_4']].rename({'level_4': 'r_type'}, axis=1)

# concat the expanded results of `d_type` and `r_type`
df5 = pd.concat([df4_ra, df4_da])

# Final layout transformation
df_out = (df5.groupby(level=[0, 1, 2, 3])
             .apply(lambda df: df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values)))
             .fillna(0)
             .droplevel(4)
         ).reset_index()
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)

   id  date  occupied  remaining r_type d_type
0  aa  q122        10          2    hey    hey
1  aa  q122        10          2    hey    hey
2  aa  q122        10          2    hey    hey
3  aa  q122        10          2    hey     hi
4  aa  q122        10          2     hi     hi
5  aa  q122        10          2     hi      0
6  bb  q222         2          1    hey      0
```

Comment: Thank you @SeaBean. I will try this and check- what exactly is the first part doing? It is creating an index gor what reason? Thanks- I’ll research

Comment: @Lynn The first part of setting index is to leave only the columns we need to work on (i.e.  `r_hi`, `r_hey`, `d_hi`, `d_hey` ) in data columns. This facilitates our 2nd step on splitting the column labels of these 4 columns. Setting these as index also helps in subsequent steps e.g. duplicating rows and the correct alignment on pd.concat.

Comment: ok and another question, lets say I have 4 types, such as r_type,d_type, l_type and e_type.
Would I have to adjust the last parts levels to 0,1,2,3,4 etc (Ive already adjusted the other steps)

Comment: Also is saying 'repeats may not contain negative values' when I use my full dataset. Is there a way around this?

Comment: @Lynn  The last part levels 0, 1, 2, 3 are actually the columns ['id', 'date', 'occupied', 'remaining'] at index.  You don't need to adjust them for more types. Level 4 is a interim row index created when we use the `.apply()` statement to compact rows with `NaN` into fewer rows.   You don't need to adjust for this level 4 too.

Comment: @Lynn  It is unexpected that the values under r_hi, r_hey, etc. which governs the number of repeating elements in column (i.e. the number of rows to repeat), can have negative values.  In such case, what number of repeating elements to create ?  If it is possible that you can simply regard these negative numbers as 0, you can change these negative values to 0 for the columns  r_hi, r_hey, d_hi, d_hey, etc. by using the code such as `df2[df2 < 0] = 0`.  Put this new code before the code `df2.columns = df2.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)`.